# Expression for asking about the material of a cloth in a store?

Tags: expressions

How do you ask about the material of a cloth when you go shopping?

Comment: What is this made of, please?

Comment: Normally in English we use 'material' to mean 'cloth' so that makes your question confusing. Do you want to ask about the type of fibre that the cloth is made from? Do you want to enquire about the price? What

Comment: "Which fabric is this?" I believe the answer would be "wool," "polyester," "cotton," etc.

Comment: What is wrong with what you've put in your question? "What material is that cloth, while I'm shopping?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Find a member of staff in the store

Step 2: Ask them "What material is this cloth made from?"

Step 3: Wait for them to find the label in the garment you are holding

Step 3a: [Optional: only applies to older members of staff] Wait for them to find their reading glasses

Step 4: Listen

---

**Alternative option:**

Step 1: Read the label in the garment yourself

Warning: This option may take the fun out of it for you. And it is unlikely to impress the teacher who clearly set you this as a question.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer helps the OP.

Comment: @Tragicomic - Step 2 provides an expression which asks, in a store, what material a cloth is made from. i.e. Step 2 is my answer to the question. The rest is just padding (mainly for my own amusement I have to be honest).